# Is there a way to share data (ex. enums) between a NodeJS Backend and a WPF C# Windows Application Frontend?

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, wpf, endpoint

I've noticed that I've been writing a small, but non-negligible amount of repeat code between my NodeJS Backend and C# WPF Frontend.

Most of the code would be things like Enums or Model classes where a backend endpoint would require an enum or properties of a Model, I would have to write an equivalent Enum or Model on the WPF application to properly do the insertion. This is okay as it works, but I'm simply wondering is there a better approach to keeping these 2 projects in sync?

Thanks!

Comment: If you used ASP.NET Web API / ASP.NET Core / WCF on your backend you wouldn't have that problem (just as if you used JavaScript on the frontend...). At the moment, there's nothing that can keep JavaScript and c# (two completely different languages) in sync like that

Comment: Most people I know who does this have some kinda utlity that can dump out type definitions (or similar) from C# types. I'm not sure if there's a standard tool for this, but for the most basic stuff I can't imagine it being very complex.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are looking for tools to create the interoperatbility or for libraries that will do this at runtime. I think there are tools that can help you with this though.

Personally I have experience with generating a C# client using [NSwagStudio](https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag). You can (among other options) use a "Swagger file" to generate a C# client.

In order to generate a swagger file from your NodeJS endpoint you might be able to use a tool like https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node to complete your tool chain. I have no experience with the latter so I don't know how it works.